# linux - useradd: group user1 exists - if you want to add this user to that group, use -g

Tags: unix

When i try to create user1 i got the error useradd: group student1 exists - if you want to add this user to that group, use -g. what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 9):

By default when you execute command `useradd user1` it will create user and group with the same name. If you don't want create a group you should provide existing one:

```
useradd -g user_group user_name
```

Read more: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/